# Detect and delete duplicates based on specific dictionary key in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates

I have a list of dictionaries where each dictionary is information about an article. Sometimes, the same article "title" repeats across dictionaries. I want to remove these duplicate dictionaries so that each article in the list of dictionaries is unique by `title` i.e. no title repeats across the dictionaries.

I have

```
data = [{'title':'abc','source':'x','url':'abcx.com'},
            {'title':'abc','source':'y','url':'abcy.com'},
            {'title':'def','source':'g','url':'defg.com'}]
```

Expected result:

```
data = [{'title':'abc','source':'x','url':'abcx.com'},
            {'title':'def','source':'g','url':'defg.com'}]
```

Comment: If you want `title` to be unique, maybe `data` should just be a dictionary with `title` as a key rather than a list of dicts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two lines with set:

```
tmp = set()
result = [tmp.add(i['title']) or i for i in data if i['title'] not in tmp]
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick way is to keep a track of titles you have seen:

```
titles_seen = set() #thank you @Mark Meyer
data = [{'title':'abc','source':'x','url':'abcx.com'},
        {'title':'abc','source':'y','url':'abcy.com'},
        {'title':'def','source':'g','url':'defg.com'}]
new_data = []
for item in data:
    if item['title'] not in titles_seen:
        new_data.append(item)
    titles_seen.add(item['title'])
```

---

As @Mark Meyer points out in the comments, you can use `title` as the key in the dictionary, which will eliminate duplicates due to the hashing of the title, or, one may define an `Entry` class, and then simply use `frozenset` (potential overkill):

```
>>> data
[<Entry title=abc source=x url=abcx.com />, <Entry title=abc source=y url=abcy.com />, <Entry title=def source=g url=defg.com />]
>>> frozenset(data)
frozenset({<Entry title=def source=g url=defg.com />, <Entry title=abc source=x url=abcx.com />})
```

---

```
class Entry:
    def __init__(self, title, source, url):
            self.title = title
            self.source = source
            self.url = url
    def __hash__(self):
            return hash(self.title)
    def __eq__(self, other):
            if isinstance(other, Entry):
                    return self.title == other.title
            return False
    def __ne__(self, other):
            return (not self.__eq__(other))
    def __repr__(self):
            return "<Entry title={} source={} url={} />".format(self.title, self.source, self.url)
```

But a better way is simply to check if the title exists before adding to the list in the first place.

Comment: Why wouldn't you make `titles_seen` a set so this isn't O(n²)?